# LORRI raw images in uncompressed format

Tags: new-horizons, raw-data, 2014-mu69

I have been solving inverse problems (upsampling) for more than 20 years to improve the resolution of bitmaps image (http://www.resampling.narod.ru). I would like to try my algorithm to improve the LORRI raw images from Ultima Thule.

But I can't work with JPG format (http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/) because compression distorts information. Can I get the raw image in the uncompress format of a PNG or TIFF?

Comment: I doubt they've been downloaded yet

Comment: also, the term "raw images" doesn't necessarily mean [RAW image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) with RAW in capital letters.

Answer (score 3):

The raw images should eventually end up at the [Planetary Data System](https://pds.nasa.gov/datasearch/data-search/). If you want them earlier for some reason, you could try asking the team, but...

Comment: They are there, but are available in jpg format (big size raw image). But no png format. (

Comment: I looked, and it seems most of them are in very large bundles, of which I was not able to download in a reasonable amount of time. But they are required to produce raw images within a reasonable amount of time of receiving the data, I think 6 months, so...

Comment: @Vitaly Just confirmed, you get from PDS an image in the FITS format, which is the standard for NASA data sources. That is a raw format without compression.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I suspected it, but didn't know it was the FITS graphic format.